# libtidy5 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, libraries, shared-library

I'm trying to install a program, which depends on `libtidy5` and getting the following message:

> wime depends on libtidy5 (>= 5.2.0); however:
> Package libtidy5 is not installed.

However, I have already installed libtidy5deb1, which is available from the repository. Unfortunately, this library does not appear to be what the program I'm trying to install needs. Or are these libraries the same and I need to do some sort of a "patch" or a "fix"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply download this [single *libtidy5* deb-package from 18.04 LTS repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libtidy5) and install it manually using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tidy-html5/libtidy5_5.2.0-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libtidy5_5.2.0-2_amd64.deb
```

then install the needed application.